# Elastic Beanstalk in AWS is only using my Dockerfile, not my Docker Compose file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-container

I want Elastic Beanstalk to call my docker-compose file when running the EC2 instance in order to spin up redis within the docker container. It is not doing so. When I run the docker-compose file using a script outside of AWS my application runs just fine. I have looked at the documentation on AWS and there isn't a clear answer on how EB is actually finding my docker compose file. I would love to ask anyone with a bit more experience for advice on how to remedy this.

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: filamentgraphql/filament-prod
    container_name: 'filament-prod-hot'
    ports: 
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: npm run build
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis:/usr/src/app/data"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT node ./server/server.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the options are explosive as I read the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html):

> You can deploy your web application as a containerized service to Elastic Beanstalk by doing **one of the following actions**:
>
> - docker-compose.yml
> - Dockerfile

If you want to keep using `Dockerfile` for your `docker-compose.yml`, rename it or place it in some subfolder so that EB does not find the `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: filamentgraphql/filament-prod
    container_name: 'filament-prod-hot'
    ports: 
      - '4000:4000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: npm run build
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis:/usr/src/app/data"
```

...but it will rebuild your docker container twice. To get around this  may as well rename your `Dockerfile` to `Dockerfile-aws` and do

```
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-aws
```